# How do i get a certain string from a column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Column name Subject

Value = Something TEST001 something

I need to get TEST001 from "Something TEST001 Something"

If there are spaces or any specials characters after the 1 of TEST001 they will be removed.

I only have this

```
SELECT   
    Subject
    , REPLACE(SUBSTRING(MailSubject, CHARINDEX('TEST', MailSubject), LEN(MailSubject)),'', '') AS Assingment
FROM    
    AssingmentEmail
```

The numbers from `TEST001` can be more but if there are any spaces or non numeric it will be removed.

Comment: What is `Something`? Is it always a constant size/name/word etc? Or does `TEST001` always start with `TEST` or finish with a number? Also what DBMS?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Something is anything. TEST001 always starts with the word TEST. It finished with any number.

Comment: This is for sql-server.

Comment: @JamesRonquillo and is it always 3 digits after TEST?

Comment: @Matt No Matt it can be more than 3 digits.

Comment: can you provide some more samples of the possible values you expect to filter, i.e. with special characters.

Comment: @ Tanner example: student name [TEST00002]  student number. I should get TEST00002 only.

Comment: The script  above give me this results TEST00002] student number. however i only want to get TEST00002.

Comment: @JamesRonquillo See my answer, works for all scenarios and lengths of TEST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments here is edited solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(v VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Something TEST001 something'),
('Something [TEST0001] something'),
('Something TEST001 something 123 something'),
('Something {TEST0001} something 123 something')

;WITH cte AS(SELECT SUBSTRING(v, CHARINDEX('TEST', v), LEN(v)) AS v FROM @t)
SELECT SUBSTRING(v, 1, PATINDEX('%[^TEST0-9]%', v) - 1) AS v FROM cte
```

Output:

```
v
TEST001
TEST0001
TEST001
TEST0001
```

Explanation:

In `cte` you are selecting substrings:

```
TEST001 something
TEST0001] something
TEST001 something 123 something
TEST0001} something 123 something
```

Then you are searching for first occurrence of symbol that is not `T E S T 0 1 2 3...9` with `%[^TEST0-9]%` and get substring till that symbol.

Comment: This looks like the best solution that covers both spaces and special characters.

Comment: I have tested this but it does not cover the space. I have sample like this Studentname TEST003 11/3/2015. I got TEST003 11/3/2015. i need to handle those spaces after the number.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a subquery.  It is easier to handle the intermediate results.  First, get rid of the part before the "TEST".  Then, take the result up the first first space:

```
select left(ms1, charindex(' ', ms1)) as TestStuff
from (select stuff(MailSubject, 1, charindex(' TEST', MailSubject), '') as ms1
      from assignment email
     ) ae
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX` & `LEN`. Also works regardless of how many digits are in the TESTXXXX.

```
SELECT MailSubject,
LEFT(SUBSTRING([MailSubject], CHARINDEX('TEST', [MailSubject]), LEN([MailSubject])), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING([MailSubject], 
CHARINDEX('TEST', [MailSubject]), LEN([MailSubject]))) - 1) AS [MailSubject]
FROM AssingmentEmail
```

INPUT:

```
MailSubject
something TEST001 something 
something TEST201 something
something TEST20122 something
something TEST601 something
```

OUTPUT:

```
MailSubject                      MailSubject
something TEST001 something      TEST001
something TEST201 something      TEST201
something TEST20122 something    TEST20122
something TEST601 something      TEST601
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93660d/1/0

Comment: works with spaces but this won't cover special characters... _If there are spaces or any specials characters after the 1_

Comment: @Tanner I am working from the specification `"The numbers from TEST001 can be more but if there are any spaces or non numeric it will be removed."` and assuming they will be removed prior to being put into the table.

Comment: I think when he says _will be removed_ he means _should be removed_, in the comment he states values like: `[TEST00002]` will be present.

Comment: yup this does not handle the spaces or special characters.

Comment: @JamesRonquillo could the special characters be known, as in will they always be `[` & `]` ot could they be anything?